# Writing different PHP code for different HTML buttons (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to write different PHP code for different HTML `<button>` elements, but apparently it applies to all the buttons on the page. Here's one of my buttons:

```
<button name="plus" id="plus" type="button" onclick="plus()">+</button>
```

Here's the function I tried to make, it applies to all the buttons on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'plus.php',
            success: function(data) {
                //
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

The questions:

1. How do I write functions for specific buttons?
2. Why do I have to write type="button" for them to work?
3. Where do I write AJAX functions? In `<head></head>` or anywhere in the body?

Comment: If you want to write a function to a specific button you have to use the atribute ID an then in js use the selector for the id like this $('#id').click(function(){........}); infact you can put the function directly in the html: <button  id="plus" type="button" onclick="plus()">+</button> then in you js you have to declare the function: function plus(){...do something.....} i think the best practice for your js code is to create a file jsfunctions.js and include with a tag  <script src="folder/to/myscripts.js"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How do I write functions for specific buttons?

You can do this by putting specific id or classes on the `button` elements so you can select a single element or groups of them at once. For example `$('#plus')` would target only the `id="plus"` element in your HTML sample.

> 2) Why do I have to write type="button" for them to work?

This is because the default `type` of a button is `submit`. Therefore if the button is in a `form` it will submit the form before your JS has time to complete.

> 3) Where do I write AJAX functions? In the head or anywhere in the body?

Either is fine, but if you put it in the `<head>` make sure you place your code in a document.ready handler.

Finally, I would suggest that you remove the `onclick="plus()"` attribute in your HTML. You don't appear to be using it and even if you were, attaching events through JS is considered much better practice over the use of archaic event attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it will apply to all button because you select all button
In Jquery when you select a specific element you have to use an id and for selecting an ID in your case you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#plus").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'plus.php',
            success: function(data) {
                //

            }
        }); }); });
```

It will work now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you already specified a method to be called when the button is clicked, the attribute `onclick` does that, so when someone clicks that button, the function plus gets called.

And if you want to do that with jQuery use the `click(function(event){...});`

Next,

> Why do I have to write type="button" for them to work?

There would be no harm if you don't use that `type="button"`, it is used when you want to use the `<button>...</button>`, for submitting a form, the default value for `type` is `button` only,

> Where do I write AJAX functions? In `<head></head>` or anywhere in the body?

You need to write that ajax part in the script, you may place the `<script></script>` either in your body or the head, anywhere you wish.

So the ajax thing would look like,

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    ....
    });
</script>
```